# Will Azure HDInsight certificate renewal affect HDInsight jobs

Tags: azure, hive, azure-powershell, azure-hdinsight

I am using the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-store#create-hdinsight-clusters-with-access-to-data-lake-storage-gen1) to renew the HDInsight certificate. I wanted to know if the certificate renewal would impact if there are any running jobs?

We have similar certificate renewal process for Automation Accounts. I have tested this for Automation account, by creating a long running runbook, and initiating the certificate renewal. The runbook execution was not affected by the certificate renewal code.

I wanted to check if anyone has tried this for HDInsight.

```
$clusterName = '<clustername>'
$resourceGroupName = '<resourcegroupname>'
$subscriptionId = '01234567-8a6c-43bc-83d3-6b318c6c7305'
$appId = '01234567-e100-4118-8ba6-c25834f4e938'
$addNewCertKeyCredential = $true
$certFilePath = 'C:\localfolder\adls.pfx'
$KeyVaultName = "my-key-vault-name"
$KeyVaultSecretName = "my-key-vault-secret-name"
$certPassword = Read-Host "Enter Certificate Password"
# certSource
# 0 - create self signed cert
# 1 - read cert from file path
# 2 - read cert from key vault
$certSource = 0

Login-AzAccount
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

if($certSource -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "Generating new SelfSigned certificate"

    $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject "CN=hdinsightAdlsCert" -KeySpec KeyExchange
    $certBytes = $cert.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $certPassword);
    $certString = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certBytes)
}
elseif($certSource -eq 1)
{

    Write-Host "Reading the cert file from path $certFilePath"

    $cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFilePath, $certPassword)
    $certString = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($certFilePath))
}
elseif($certSource -eq 2)
{

    Write-Host "Reading the cert file from Azure Key Vault $KeyVaultName"

    $cert = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Name $KeyVaultSecretName)
    $certValue = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cert.SecretValueText)
    $certObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList $certValue, $null,"Exportable, PersistKeySet"

    $certBytes = $certObject.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $certPassword.SecretValueText);

    $certString =[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certBytes)
}

if($addNewCertKeyCredential)
{
    Write-Host "Creating new KeyCredential for the app"
    $keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())
    New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $appId -CertValue $keyValue -EndDate $cert.NotAfter -StartDate $cert.NotBefore
    Write-Host "Waiting for 7 minutes for the permissions to get propagated"
    Start-Sleep -s 420 #7 minutes
}

Write-Host "Updating the certificate on HDInsight cluster..."

Invoke-AzResourceAction `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters' `
    -ResourceName $clusterName `
    -ApiVersion '2015-03-01-preview' `
    -Action 'updateclusteridentitycertificate' `
    -Parameters @{ ApplicationId = $appId; Certificate = $certString; CertificatePassword = $certPassword.ToString() } `
    -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it. I believe your issue would have been resolved. But still, for other viewers, it is not recommended to run the certificate renewal process if a job is running in the production cluster as it would might lead to inconsistent errors.